# expected value of light bulbs

Tags: probability, probability-theory

There are 50 light bulbs in a room each with its own switch. If a light bulb is on, Dick turns it off and if it is off,
he turns it on. Initially all light bulbs are off. After 50 
flips and assuming that Dick chooses switches to be 
flipped
randomly, what is the expected number of light bulbs on in the room rounded to the nearest natural number?

how would you attempt to find the expected value?
Any help on this will be highly appreciated
Thanks